# Comma separated string from what FKs reference

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have three tables:

1) name

```
IDname | Name
-------------
1      | Volk
2      | Molk
3      | Yolk
```

2) company

```
IDcompany | Company
------------------
1         | Lucellous
2         | Monstrous
```

3) name_company, which has a many-to-one relationship with name (table 1) and two foreign keys

```
IDname_company | IDname | IDcompany
1              | 1      | 1
2              | 2      | 1
3              | 2      | 2
```

I need a query that will give me this:

```
IDresult | Name | Company
--------------------------------------
1        | Volk | Lucellous
2        | Molk | Lucellous, Monstrous
3        | Yolk |
```

How can I do it? I work with SQLite and maybe later I'll switch to Firebird.

Comment: how about creating a function to get the company names separated by comma based on `IDname` ?

Comment: Which DBMS do you use? Oracle and Postgres both support the concept of string aggregation through concatenation as list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a comma-separated string from multiple strings, use the [group_concat](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat) function.
The strings are either from all records returned in a subquery:

```
SELECT IDname AS IDresult,
       Name,
       (SELECT group_concat(Company)
        FROM company
        WHERE IDcompany IN (SELECT IDcompany
                            FROM name_company
                            WHERE IDname = name.IDname))
FROM name
```

or from all records in a group defined with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT name.IDname AS IDresult,
       name.Name,
       group_concat(company.Company)
FROM name
LEFT JOIN name_company ON name.IDname            = name_company.IDname
LEFT JOIN company      ON name_company.IDcompany = company.IDcompany
GROUP BY name.IDname
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite supports the group_concat() string aggregation function, see http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html for use in queries like:

```
select id, group_concat(<string_column>)
from <table>
group by id;
```

You'll need to substitute your own query.